# PostgreSQL: Help me figure out how to use table aliases

Tags: postgresql, join, alias

Please save the remaining hair on my head and help me make aliases for statements such as these, where I am joining a table with its lookup table

```
//this does the location lookup
SELECT 
ludevice.device,
ludevice.description,
lulocation.location_long
FROM mopdb.ludevice
LEFT JOIN lulocation ON (ludevice.location_id = lulocation.location_id)
WHERE (ludevice.location_id = 1)
ORDER BY ludevice.device_id
```

*edit* removed the confusing comment

*edit* the desired result is a statement which achieves this functionality with fewer characters

Comment: Does the comment above mean that you solved your problem? If that is the cause you have two options. Either vote to close the question or write an answer to your own question such that others who have similar problems may use your solution.

Comment: What exactly is the desired result?  A shorter query?

Comment: The comment is just a personal note from when I finally got the query to work in the first place. I'd like to shorten the query by aliasing the table names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to use table aliases in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040883/trying-to-use-table-aliases-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  d.device,
  d.description,
  l.location_long
FROM mopdb.ludevice d
LEFT JOIN lulocation l ON (d.location_id = l.location_id)
WHERE (d.location_id = 1)
ORDER BY d.device_id
```

or slightly shorter thanks to `USING`:

```
SELECT 
  d.device,
  d.description,
  l.location_long
FROM mopdb.ludevice d
LEFT JOIN lulocation l USING (location_id)
WHERE (d.location_id = 1)
ORDER BY d.device_id
```